SwiftUI @Published Property Updates Not Reflecting in UI
I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I need to update a label based on data changes in an ObservableObject. Despite my efforts, the label updates are reflected in the debug console but not in the UI. Here are the relevant parts of my code:
import SwiftUI
class SimplePredictor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var label: String = "N/A"
    
    func updateLabel() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.label = "Updated Label"
            print("Label set to: \(self.label)") // Debugging print
        }
    }
}

class SimpleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var predictor = SimplePredictor()
}

struct SimpleContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = SimpleViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.predictor.label)
                .onReceive(viewModel.predictor.$label) { newLabel in
                    print("Label received: \(newLabel)") // Debugging print
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.predictor.updateLabel()
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SimpleContentView()
    }
}

Issue:
The label prints correctly in the debug console as

Label received: N/A
Label received: Updated Label
Label set to: Updated Label

However, the label in the UI remains "N/A" and does not update. Why are the updates to the @Published property not being reflected in the SwiftUI view, and how can I resolve this issue?
I am using Xcode 15.4.

Nested ObservableObjects don't work without manually sending objectWillChange. Search "nested ObservableObject" for lots of discussion on the topic.

Change to struct SimplePredictor. If you are stuck on iOS16, have a look at this link  Monitoring data. If targeting iOS17  Managing model data in your app for how to manage data in your app.

You've got one class too many here

As per the suggestions, these two approaches both worked.
#1 Using Observable macro (ios17)
@Observable class SimplePredictor {
    var label: String = "N/A"
    
    func updateLabel() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.label = "Updated Label"
            print("Label set to: \(self.label)") // Debugging print
        }
    }
}

class SimpleViewModel {
    var predictor = SimplePredictor()
}

struct SimpleContentView: View {
    var viewModel = SimpleViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.predictor.label)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.predictor.updateLabel()
        }
    }
}

#2 Workaround of nested ObservableObject using a targeted View with single level of object structure
class SimplePredictor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var label: String = "N/A"
    
    func updateLabel() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.label = "Updated Label"
            print("Label set to: \(self.label)") // Debugging print
        }
    }
}

class SimpleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var predictor = SimplePredictor()
}

struct SimpleContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = SimpleViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PredictorLabel(predictor: viewModel.predictor)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.predictor.updateLabel()
        }
    }
}

struct PredictorLabel: View {
    @ObservedObject var predictor: SimplePredictor
    var body: some View {
        Text(predictor.label)
    }
}


You've got one class too many here. Remove SimpleViewModel, in SwiftUI the View struct hierarchy is the view model and it auto-generates UI objects depending on the context/platform.

This is simplified version of code. ViewModel keeps other data models
